# How do I filter by multiple values of muliple categorical variables to make a plot in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have data like this:

```
type      source   weight
cabbage   store    2.2
cabbage   farm     2.3
cabbage   farm     1.9
celery    store    2.1
celery    farm     2.0
celery    store    1.7
turnip    farm     1.5
turnip    store    2.5
```

1) How do I make a boxplot of weights for cabbage and celery combined? I.e. a single boxplot in which the data comes from the column `weight`, but only if the column type is "cabbage" or "celery".

2) How do I make a boxplot filtering by both categorical variables? I.e. a single boxplot in which the data comes from the column `weight`, but only if the column `type` is "cabbage" or "celery" AND the column `source` is "farm".

Comment: `boxplot(df$weight[df$type %in% c("cabbage","celery"), ])` (where `df` is your data frame).

Comment: I edited the question to be slightly more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide `boxplot` with the filtered data as follows

```
df<-data.frame(type=c("cabbage","cabbage","cabbage","celery","celery","celery","turnip","turnip"), weight=c(2.2,2.3,1.9,2.1,2.0,1.7,1.5,2.5))
> df
     type weight
1 cabbage    2.2
2 cabbage    2.3
3 cabbage    1.9
4  celery    2.1
5  celery    2.0
6  celery    1.7
7  turnip    1.5
8  turnip    2.5
> boxplot(df$weight[df$type %in% c("cabbage","celery")])
```

This uses plain strings for `type`, but it will also work for factors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I want to do this with more than one categorical variable? I'm going to edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Just edit the selection criteria to add `& df$source == "farm"`